# Class objects not being callable after instantiation

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
class Swimmers:
    """ Creates objects for each swimmer with unique details"""

    instances = []

    def __init__(self, fName = "None", lName = "None", house = "None", time = "None"):
        self.fName = getfName()
        self.lName = getlName()
        self.house = getHouse()
        self.time = getTime()
        self.__class__.instances.append(self)


    @classmethod
    def printInstances(cls):
        for instance in cls.instances:
            print(instance)


def test():

    style, swimmerNumber = raceDetails()

    for x in range(int(swimmerNumber)):
        y = re.sub(".0", "", str(x))
        string = "swimmer" + y
        print("\n" + string + "\n")
        string = Swimmers()
        x -= 1
```

I need to create a module that takes various inputs and saves each iteration as a class object. The function raceDetails() simply gets the type of race and the number of swimmers, nothing wrong with that part. The functions getX() are simply input functions with some error checking. The issue is that trying to call the objects or any of their variables after everything has been entered simply gives me:

```
>>> swimmer0.fName
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    swimmer0.fName
NameError: name 'swimmer0' is not defined
```

I've added a list of every object created by the class ('instances') which prints:

```
<__main__.Swimmers object at 0x04182F88>
<__main__.Swimmers object at 0x04182E50>
```

and so on, which, combined with the working getX() functions, means the objects are being instantiated perfectly fine. I've tried everything I can think of, including nonlocals, changing scopes, adding intermediary functions, but none of it seems to work. The only thing I can think of is an issue with reference generation in the module namespace.

It's not essential that I use classes for this, and I could very easily use dictionaries or the like, but I want to try and learn classes as best as I can.

Using Windows 10, Python 3.9.2 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're setting the `string` variable equal to the variable name you want ('swimmer0', 'swimmer1'...), but then you set `string` equal to the `Swimmers` class. Dynamically setting variables names is possible in python, but typically you'll want to use a dictionary (or another collections object) to store the objects.

```py
def test():

    style, swimmerNumber = raceDetails()

    swimmers_dict = {}
    for x in range(int(swimmerNumber)):
        y = re.sub(".0", "", str(x))
        string = "swimmer" + y
        print("\n" + string + "\n")
        swimmers_dict[x] = Swimmers()
        x -= 1

    return swimmers_dict
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the issue. The dictionary is storing the references, and I can see them, but it gives the same traceback error, saying that the names are not defined. Would there be a way to effectively manually assign the dictionary references to the object names to allow for calling or would the entire module need a rewrite?

Comment: You'll need to reference the objects using the dictionary `swimmers_dict['swimmer1']`

Comment: The assignment in the dictionary is 0, 1, etc. but calling these using `swimmers_dict['0']` only raises a "Key Error", specifically: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    swimmers_dict['0']
KeyError: '0'`

Comment: ahhh I see, it's because the key isn't a string so call the dict like this: `swimmers_dict[0]`. Or just fix my example to use `swimmers_dict[string] = ...` so you can use `swimmer0` etc... You can always check the keys of a dictionary using `dict.keys()` as well

Comment: Even that doesn't fix the issue. I added a `__call__` function to the class, created another function to test namespace issues, and even made `swimmers_dict` global. Manually instantiating has no issues, and all objects created by `test()` are viewable in the `instances[]` dictionary. Which leads me to believe that as the function `test()` is terminated, the references to the objects are being destroyed, or some similar behaviour which is leading to this issue. Time constraints mean I have to abandon this problem for now, but feel free to append any insights. Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: are you capturing the output of the function? `swimmers_dict = test()`

Comment: Yes. I created another function which had `swimmers_dict = test()` as its only function and it still didn't work.

Comment: Where are you accessing `swimmers_dict`?

Comment: Preferably from an enclosing function that would link together all other functionalities into one main loop that is iterated over until the module is terminated